# How to search keyword and hashtags or symbol?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, yii

I have a input box in which user can enter either keyword or #tag word and after click on search button it will find that field which have that keyword or #tags.
1. I tried %like% it worked but if search  only for #m it is giving me all words which have m letter.
2. I tried regular expression also 
 like this
 `WHERE notes REGEXP '[[:<:]]{$f['activityId']}[[:>:]]'` 
but it is not working for #tag or other symbol.
3. I use also full text search  but it is not working for symbol
 i refer from here  for full text , and i don't want to recompile my mysql.
[Full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html)

Is there any way to search key word with #tag and with symbol 
Like : @amitesh,#amitesh,amitesh etc.

Comment: Have you already tried escaping the characters? Like, \# instead of #, for example? In regex buddy, \# finds # but interestingly considers the character right after it as a word boundary. That could make the task more difficult, but not insurmountable. How are the strings processed? You might be able to get away with something like `^\#.*?$` or `\#.*?\s` depending on how you're processing input.

Comment: yes i tried in full text search but it was not working there,i did not tried in regexp , i will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql> SELECT 'foo #amitesh bar' REGEXP '([[:<:]]|#|@)amitesh[[:>:]]';
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 'foo #amitesh bar' REGEXP '([[:<:]]|#|@)amitesh[[:>:]]' |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                       1 |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

I think the `#` and the word start (`[[:<:]]`) are not playing well together.  So, to look for any of `@amitesh,#amitesh,amitesh`, I decided on "word start OR # OR @".

Comment: its not working i tried
 'post_content  REGEXP "([[:<:]]|#)#StarScreenAwards[[:>:]]"'

Comment: Remove the second `#`.

Comment: now its working, but i want to search input as @amitesh or #amitesh not simply amitesh

Comment: Yeah, but the `@` or `#` gets in the way.  `"([[:<:]]|#|@)StarScreenAwards[[:>:]]"`

Comment: If you want to search for _just_ `@Rick`, then `REGEXP "@Rick[[:>:]]"`.  That is, you need to look at the request to figure out _which_ regexp to use.